# Magento 2 SASS for modules on child themes

Tags: sass

I want to change some styles in single module. I create own child theme for Snowdog and everything it's compiled by frontools.

Have you got some suggestion how i can do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Sass blank theme works similar to the default LESS compilation but the path/filename is slightly different, for example if you want to extend the Magento Checkout module styling you'll need to add the following file:

```
app/design/frontend/Glamorous/master/Magento_Catalog/styles/_widgets.scss
```

For more examples and to se how it imports them look at the Snowdogs blank theme

```
vendor/snowdog/theme-blank-sass/styles/styles.scss
```

If the file you need isn't in `styles.scss` it's just a case of importing your own SCSS file in your theme. The Sass blank theme is much more flexible than the standard M2 LESS compilation.